# Jackson Object Mapper readvalue in bytes returning a object with all fields initialized to null

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules

I'm trying to deserialize a byte array into a java type using jackson object mapper.

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class A {
     String s;
     String b;
    }

   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)   
   public class B {
     String c;
     String b;
   }

      @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
       @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)   
       public class C {
         List<CustomType> x;
       }
```

and using the jackson method,

```
objectMapper.readValue(byte[] data, Class<T> type).
```

As i am not sure what object the byte array contains, i want to it to fail when it cannot create an object of the specified type. However, objectMapper returns an **object with all fields initialized to null**. How do i avoid this behavior?

```
Ex: 
byte[] b; //contains Class B data
byte[] a; //contains Class A data
byte[] c// contains Class C data
A a = objectMapper.readValue(c, A.class) is returning 
{s=null, b = null}
```

and this is ow i have configured the ObjectMapper,

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(HandlerInstantiator handlerInstantiator) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.handlerInstantiator(handlerInstantiator);
        builder.failOnEmptyBeans(false);
        builder.failOnUnknownProperties(false);
        builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        builder.timeZone("UTC");
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for the response. I have included everything needed to reproduce. for simplicity i have removed the getters and setters for the java objects.

Comment: @Bharath No you did not.

Comment: @lexicore did i now? please see the edit.

Comment: Define _when it cannot create_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: hmm.. from a byte array containing data of Object of type Class C, but i am trying to deserialize it into an Object of type Class A. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> objectMapper returns an object with all fields initialized to null. How
>   do i avoid this behavior?

Fields in input object that match target class will not be set to null.
Therefore, make sure that there are some matching fields (fields with same name).

If you do not want null, you may have default values for those fields.
This may be done

- at field declaration `String s="default value"`;
- in default, parameterless constructor. Jackson will invoke this constructor, then set values for matching fields from JSON data.

If your source json is totally different, not single matching field then you will get object where every field is null.

Comment: thats wat i am asking. How do i avoid this behavior of returning an object with all null values.

Comment: @Bharath, I extended my answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` says you ignore unknown properties. So if you unmarshal `B` data as `A` instance, the `c` property is ignored, just not filled so this is why you get `null`.

Remove this annotation an you should start getting `JsonMappingException` or similar.

`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` is just for serialization.

Comment: if it cannot resolve any of the fields then it returns an object with values initialized to null. However, if only some of the fields are resolved, it does throw an exception. How do i handle scenario 1?